# Asp.net web page does not scroll vertically

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, scroll

The vertical scrollbar at the right-hand side of my asp.net web page is always greyed out, even if there is content out of view further down the page.

I think its related to the html css class but I'm not sure. I have tried many different variations there with no luck. I am launching with IE8 from visual studio.

html

```
{
   overflow: ??
}
```

I am using a master page w/ content place holder. Like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeBehind="SummaryView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports.SummaryView" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<link href="Style/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="PlanInfo" runat="server" style="float:right; height:200px; width:720px; margin-left:20px;" ></div>
<br />
<div id="UserInfo" runat="server" style="float:right; height:200px; width:720px; margin-left:20px;" ></div>
<br />
<div id="SummaryInfo" runat="server" style="float:right; height:200px; width:720px;     margin-left:20px;" ></div>
</asp:Content>
```

EDIT

I think this may be the relevant CSS section (in my master page)

```
    #form1
    {
        overflow:visible; 
        height: 999px;
        width: 1152px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 12px;
        left: 6px;
    }
```

Comment: Posting the full CSS that you think is causing an issue would be a wise idea. My first instinct is that `overflow` is set incorrectly.

Comment: If I set overflow : auto under the #form1 section then I get a scrollbar on my form, but thats not the html scrollbar for the document generally thats on the rightmost side of the page.

Comment: What elements have `overflow` properties set on them? It seems that the `overflow:visible;` with `#form1` is a stopgap measure alleviating the "symptoms" something like an `overflow:hidden;` elsewhere.

Comment: I changed #form1 to overflow: hidden, and the html { } css class to overflow: auto. Seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could press F12 in IE and launch the Developer Toolbar. Use the select tool, to select the element with the greyed out scrollbar and see which css is actual applied to that element. You can even try within this toolbar to make some adjustments to the css to see the differences.

I think this link will give you some details about how to use the tool:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/IE_dev_toolbar.aspx

If you can't find out why it's not working you can post the actual css here so we can maybe help you.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot. I had to set my form position to relative rather than absolute along with an overflow: auto attribute it the html { } css class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is definitely in CSS, and is unrelated to the fact that the page is written in ASP.NET. You probably have overflow:hidden set somewhere on your page, which is causing content outside that element not to be shown, thus no scrollbars are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting height: 101%; in the body rule and see if that fixes it :-)

Comment: Doesnt do anything in the body rule but if I put that in the html rule then a scrollbar appears, however it doesnt actually do anything when you scroll. I think its possibly related to the positioning of the form as relative/ absolute or something? Not sure.

Comment: I wouldn't apply CSS rules to the form in any case - move them to the body element. Then I would simply start commenting out rules in my CSS to locate the offending syntax. ChristiaanV's suggestion to use a tool is a good one :-)